# Возможно ли сделать паузу в несколько секунд между двумя аудио в PyQT5/Pyside2?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qmediaplayer

Есть простой код вроде

```
self.player = QMediaPlayer()
self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

self.playlist.addMedia(QUrl.fromLocalFile("AUDIO_1.wav"))
self.playlist.addMedia(QUrl.fromLocalFile("AUDIO_2.wav"))

self.player.play()
```

Когда он выполняется сначала играется AUDIO_1, и сразу же как оно заканчивается начинает  играть AUDIO_2. Никаких пауз между двумя аудио нет, а хотелось бы, и чтобы эту паузу можно было настраивать по времени. Возможно ли это как-то сделать? Уже пробовал несколько вариантов:

Через QEventLoop:

```
self.loop = QEventLoop()
def start_loop(duration):
    QTimer.singleShot(duration, self.loop.quit)
    self.loop.exec_()
start_loop(3000)
```

Заготовкой файла с тишиной, например в одну секунду, и добавлением (возможно несколько раз):

```
self.file = QUrl.fromLocalFile("silence_3s.wav")
self.playlist.addMedia(self.file)
```

Но что первый, что второй способ кажутся кривыми костылями и наверняка должен существовать более правильный и красивый способ внедрения паузы без них или без переопределения класса.

Answer (score 0):

Можно при смене текущего элемента плейлиста приостанавливать воспроизведение

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton("Play", self)
        self.button.move(50, 50)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.resume)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/arise/share/ringout.wav")))
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/arise/share/ringout.wav")))
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/arise/share/ringout.wav")))
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.pause)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(3000)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.resume)



    def pause(self,index):
        if index == -1:
            print('playlist is over')
            return
        print(f'current playlist pos: {index}')
        self.player.pause()
        self.timer.start()

    def resume(self):
        print('playing...')
        self.player.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(window.exec())
```